# java swing: enable disable a specific key binding for a component

Tags: java, swing

In my case I want to be able to enable and disable `ctrl F6` on `JDesktopPane`.

Right now I am disabling it in this way:

```
KeyStroke remove = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F6, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
InputMap im = desktop.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
im.put(remove, "none");
```

And it seems to works the key binding is no more active.

I don't know how to re-enable it, or what to save before disabling for enabling it again later.

Thanks for the help

**UPDATE1:**

based on the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76689063/399637
I tried to work on the `Action`, this is a test code:

```
desktop = new JDesktopPane();
KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F6, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
InputMap im = desktop.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
ActionMap am = desktop.getActionMap();
String key = (String)im.get(keyStroke);
Action action = am.get(key);
assert action != null;
action.setEnabled(false);
```

but It doesn't work, `control f6` is still enabled in `JDesktopPane`.

**UPDATE2:**

I was able to make it to work using a wrapper class for the action, non a very good solution but it seems to work:

```
    private static class ActionWrapper extends AbstractAction{
        
        private final Action action;
        
        private boolean active = true;
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            
            if(active){         
                action.actionPerformed(evt);
            }   
        }
    }
```

and then the code:

```
desktop = new JDesktopPane();
KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F6, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
InputMap im = desktop.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
ActionMap am = desktop.getActionMap();
String key = (String)im.get(keyStroke);
Action action = am.get(key);
assert action != null;
actionWrapper = new ActionWrapper(action);
am.put(key, actionWrapper);
```

and then `setActive(boolean)` on the wrapper class.

If someone wants to review this solution.

Comment: *"but It doesn't work, control f6 is still enabled in JDesktopPane."* -- it may be that you're using the wrong input map. Please create and post a valid [mre] with your question code that we can copy/paste and run, similar to that seen within my answer.

Comment: You right. I posted an edit while you wrote your comments. I didn't posted a reproducible example just a test I did on my code.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to get the original key value and use it to get the original Action held by the ActionMap, save that value and then replace it when you want to restore the key's original function:

```
KeyStroke remove = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F6, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
InputMap im = desktop.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
Object keyValue = im.get(remove);
ActionMap am = desktop.getActionMap();

// store this original action somewhere   
Action originalAction = am.get(keyValue);
```

Then again, later when you want to restore the f6 ctrl-down key stroke to original function, put that action back into the action map, associating it with the key value in the input map.

---

Actually, you can use `.enabled(true)` and `.enabled(false)` on the Action associated with the key stroke of interest if you do not disassociate the key from the action. For example, in the code below, I can enable and disable a JTextArea's ability to paste text using ctrl-V by enabling and disabling the associated action with the ctrl-V keystroke.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestInputActionMaps extends JPanel {
    private JCheckBox enableAction = new JCheckBox("Enable Action", true);
    private KeyStroke controlV = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("This is text", 10, 30);
    private InputMap inputMap = textArea.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
    private ActionMap actionMap = textArea.getActionMap();    
    String ctrlVKey = (String) inputMap.get(controlV);
    Action ctrlVAction = actionMap.get(ctrlVKey);
    
    public TestInputActionMaps() {
        enableAction.addItemListener(e -> checkBoxChanged(e));
        
        
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(enableAction);
        
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(scrollPane);
    }
    
    private void checkBoxChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            ctrlVAction.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            ctrlVAction.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            TestInputActionMaps mainPanel = new TestInputActionMaps();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: why it does't work `desktop.getActionMap().get(keyStroke).setEnabled(boolean);` ?

Comment: @res1: why should that code work? That doesn't make sense, not if you unplug the input map from the action map for that keystroke?

Comment: An `Action` can be enabled or disabled, I was thinking you can access directly to the action associated with the key binding and disable / enabled it without removing the key binding from the component

Comment: You can disable the action if you do not dissociate the key from the action. For example, see the code above.

Comment: I am not able to do the same with the `Action`, I will update my question with my test code

Comment: @res1: *"but It doesn't work, control f6 is still enabled in JDesktopPane."* -- it may be that you're using the wrong input map. Please create and post a valid [mre] with your question code that we can copy/paste and run, similar to that seen within my answer.